# WPF - Styles with Custom Properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, attachedbehaviors

I'm developing a document number checking on my application and I wrote an attached behavior to textbox to check the text. Here's the behavior code:

```
 public class CPFTextBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsCPFPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("IsCPF", typeof(bool), typeof(CPFTextBehavior),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCPFProperty = IsCPFPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        public static bool GetIsCPF(TextBox tb)
        {
            return (bool)tb.GetValue(IsCPFProperty);
        }

        public bool IsCPF
        {
            get { return GetIsCPF(AssociatedObject); }
            private set { AssociatedObject.SetValue(IsCPFPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.TextChanged += LocusProject.Validacao.CPF_CNPJValidation.ValidateCPF;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += LocusProject.Validacao.CPF_CNPJValidation.ValidateCPFMask;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, LocusProject.Validacao.CPF_CNPJValidation.PastingCPFMask);
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += Interactivity.PreventInsertKey;

        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= LocusProject.Validacao.CPF_CNPJValidation.ValidateCPF;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= LocusProject.Validacao.CPF_CNPJValidation.ValidateCPFMask;
            DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, LocusProject.Validacao.CPF_CNPJValidation.PastingCPFMask);
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= Interactivity.PreventInsertKey;
        }
    }
```

And here's what i'm doing on my ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:i="clr-namespace:LocusProject">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TextFields">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.GotFocus">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000" Value="White"/>
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3500000" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.LostFocus">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000" Value="LightBlue"/>
                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3500000" Value="White"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="CPFField" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextFields}">
            <Setter Property="i:CPFTextBehavior.IsCPF" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

But here's the thing. It says "Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation." and I can't get it to work.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The TargetInvocationException has an InnerException property. Please check that for the location of the real exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the value of the IsCPF property, but you have registered that property as read only.

You need to:

1. Change the registration of the property:

   ```
   static readonly DependencyProperty IsCPFProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCPF", typeof(bool),  typeof(CPFTextBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
   ```
2. Add a SetIsCPF method:

   ```
   public static bool SetIsCPF(TextBox tb, bool value)
   {
       tb.SetValue(IsCPFProperty, value);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It worked! I have one question left, though. Do i really need to insert the tags 
            <int:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <i:CPFTextBehavior>
                    
                </i:CPFTextBehavior>
            </int:Interaction.Behaviors>
Inside every textbox ? It just doesn't work when I simply set "IsCPF" to true in the style.

Comment: That's the standard way of attaching Interaction.Behaviours to objects. Looking at your code, I can't see how you are using IsCPF. Might it be a remnant from the old way of creating attached behaviours, prior to the Expression Blend SDK?

Comment: I might be a little lost. I started developing this application a month ago, I didn't have Expression Blend in that time. So I imported System.Windows.Interactivity as a reference in my project (I'm using Visual C# 2010). The code i'm using in the window for a "CPFish" TextBox is
 <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,77,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MaxLength="14" Style="{StaticResource CPFField}" >
I thought that was all I needed. Is there a way to do that or I have to include those tags (Interaction.Behaviors and stuff) in every TextBox?Thanks